# Is there a precedent for Girl Meets World?

Tags: spin-off, girl-meets-world

Disney Channel's *Girl Meets World* is appropriately called a spin-off of ABC's 1990s hit *Boy Meets World*.  However, there are some seemingly unique aspects:

- Is it not a "typical" spin-off.  Examples like *NCIS* from *JAG* or *Laverne and Shirley* from *Happy Days*. Characters that are friends, family, or in some way intersected with the parent, but otherwise a unique series.
- It is not a re-boot.  An example is *Hawaii Five-O*.  The new version re-uses the same concept and some character names, but that's all.
- It is not a "next generation."  *Star Trek*, *Degrassi*, *Saved By the Bell (The New Class)* for example.  A future time from the parent, but with all new characters and stories.
- It is not a re-union special.  Anyone remember the Brady wedding?

In other spin-offs, characters from the parent series are either absent or at most make occasional cameo guest appearances.  With *Girl Meets World* there are at least two characters- Cory and Topanga- who play an integral role, and many others- Shawn and Eric in particular- have regular recurring parts.

Has any other series ever done anything close?

Comment: I've not seen it but the description of the show sounds like a "next generation" version to me... It's about the next generation in the Matthews family, Cory's daughter, Riley.

Comment: `It is not a "next generation."` Isn't that exactly what it is?

Comment: "In other spin-offs, characters from the parent series are either absent or at most make occasional cameo guest appearances" Huh? So how about "Frasier"? "Better Call Saul"? "Angel"? "Major Crimes"? "Joey"? "Private Practice"? "Sam & Cat"? Etc.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Though isn't it rather seldom for the first/previous generation to have such big roles in a "next generation" show - not to mention that the main character of the NG, is the children of the main character of the 1stG?

Comment: Does the final season of "Scrubs" count as a spin-off?

Comment: @OrangeDog I was thinking of Scrubs myself, but I believe season 9 is officially just another season of the same show, even though it also goes by the name "Scrubs: Med School".

Answer (score 2):

The only programme I know of close to this concept is the BBC programme "Still open all hours".

The original programme " Open all hours" was broadcast 1976 to 1985 and starred Ronnie Barker as shopkeeper Arkwright and David Jason as his assistant Granville.  Many plots followed Arkwright pursuing the district nurse Gladys with amorous intent.

Still Open All Hours debuted in 2013, the setting is still the shop with David Jason still playing Granville, he now owns the shop, Arkwright having passed on.  The only other character from the original is nurse Gladys now retired.